# BottomSheetDialogFragment with rounded corners and fragment container

Tags: android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, rounded-corners, android-bottomsheetdialog

I trying to create BottomSheetDialogFragment with rounded corners which contain fragment container.
I did the correct drawable and apply to xml of this fragment.
code:

```
public class ContainerFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_delivery_container, null);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    // тут делаю так, чтобы фон под удалёнными краями из-за скругления был прозрачным
    ((View) view.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

/*getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, ProvidersFragment.createInstance(), "TASGGGG")
            .commit();*/
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BottomSheetDialog bDialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    return bDialog;
}

/*    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_delivery_container, null);
    getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, ProvidersFragment.createInstance(), "TASGGGG")
            .commit();
    return view;
}*/

....
}
```

In the current implementation of the code, everything is fine (corners are rounded), only the fragment transaction is commented out. If i'll uncomment, it will throw an error that the "fragment does not have a View". Accordingly, if i'll uncomment onCreateView, then edges of this View appear and I can not do anything with this